# Unable to restrict Multiple File Uploads using Lightning:FileUpoad

Tags: fileupload

Am using LightningFileUpload component with Multiple set to false.But i still get the option to upload multiple files, upload button is not disabled after single file upload. Will this false attribute not work? Any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

The `multiple` attribute prevents the user from *selecting* multiple files at a time. It does not prevent the user from uploading more files to a record.

You will need to find out how many files the record has and dynamically enable/disable the upload button. For example, implement an aura enabled apex method that returns a list of content document link records for a given record ID, and use the count of records returned to the frontend to determine whether the upload button should be enabled or disabled.

Comment: Yes, i got it now, thank you for responding.

Answer (score 0):

based on Akiradev's answer, I remembered I did something similar in a project:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ContentVersion getExistingFile(String recordId){
    List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId LIMIT 1];
    if(cdls.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return [SELECT ContentDocumentId, FileType, Title, PathOnClient FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :cdls[0].ContentDocumentId LIMIT 1];
}
```

My UseCase was a bit different, I needed to show the file in the FileUpload Cmp (which was custom developed), but based on this method you can write your method which just returns a boolean if there are files and false if there are no files.

Hope this helps you also.

Regards,
Bernhard

Comment: Sure, thank you, this helps a lot.